# How to display value stored in database on the table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

This is the troublesome table created: http://jsfiddle.net/ofd3nox3/

Now, I have some issue to display the value stored in database for this table per user.

For instance, a user said she's available on Thursdays in the morning, Friday and Saturday in the afternoon. This stored in the database this way:
[image]

I can call the value via ajax on page load, but just not sure how to color the particular `'td' of the table that carries this value.

This is how the table look like, notice the value it carries on the `td`.
[image]

How I match the value with `<td>` is, I will add '-1' after Thrs for the '1' indicate morning, '2' indicates afternoon and 3 evening.
So whichever  that carries Thrs-1 will be green in color.The same method goes for afternoon and Evening. These values could be in array two which stored as comma separated value in DB.

I tried the following which actually made all `<td>` values to Thrs-1 and applied the color red to them.

MY AJAX that fetches the table values from DB:

```
$(function()
    {
        alert("hi");
        var id = '<?php echo $id;?>';
        var data;
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: '/profile/getAvail.php?id='+id,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                alert(data[i].morning);
                var morn = data[i].morning+"-1";

                //$("#greeny td").text(data[i].morning+"-1").css("background-color","#ff0000");
            }
        }
        });
    });
```

Guys if don't get what I mean exactly, please do ask in the comment, I need to sort this asap.Thank you for your kind help !!!

Comment: Now you have the issue to display the stored result from db or table color issue?

Comment: Problem  is to color the <td> value from db  in the table.

Comment: I don't understand your question, and your db design seems to be a disaster...

Comment: @KevinSimple, ignore the DB, now how do I search through each <td> that has text = Thrs-1 and change the text to "test"?

Comment: i am writing now, give me a sec

Comment: @KevinSimple, Sure, Thanks a lot

Comment: @Vani, try the code below, let me know if it works or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 //Loop all the td 
$("td").each(function() {

//if found td contains 'Thrs-1', then override the value to 'test'
if($(this).text().indexOf('Thrs-1') > -1)
{
  $(this).text('test');
 }

});
```

Comment: Perfect One! Thank you :)